# Google Tag cant fire event trigger on Elementor

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager, elementor

I have `img` element under `ahref` that created using elementor in Wordpress, below are the codes:

```
<div class="elementor-column-wrap  elementor-element-populated">
    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-39fe989 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="39fe989" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <div class="elementor-image">
                <a href="https://example.com/go" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="golink">
                    <img width="461" height="335" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner.png" 
                     class="attachment-large size-large" 
                     alt="cat" 
                     srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/bannerpng 461w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner-300x218.png 300w" 
                     sizes="(max-width: 461px) 100vw, 461px" />                             
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Reality, above code was generated by `elementor` (i didn't make a code)...

in tag manager's trigger, I have tried to setup trigger in:

1. `just click`, with filter `click` contain `class` **"golink"** --> wont fire
2. `all elements`, with filter `click` contain `class` **"elementary"** --> wont fire
3. `all elements`, with filter `click` contain `element` **"img"** --> wont fire

any idea to solve this ?

Thank You in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to set up tracking for an affiliate banner.  Sometimes GTM can be finicky.  Here's what I would do to figure it out.

1. Use debug mode in GTM
2. Make sure you have a global track all clicks event (optional)
3. Click on the image
4. Go to Variables (on the debug)
5. Assuming you set up the variable in the GTM UI, you should see what you need to target.
6. Make sure there are no "spaces " in the fields.

[image]